# Optimizing Store Procedure for multiple inserts

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, insert, sql-insert

Database : Aurora DB (MySQL)

**Schema :**

```
Table 1 : Department (d_id, d_name)
Table 2 : Student_Department (s_id, d_id)
```

In Stored procedure, first we insert **Department** details and then using that id, inserting multiple records in **Student_Department** table in loop.

**Stored Procedure :**

```
WHILE index < numOfStudents DO

            ...

            INSERT INTO department (d_name)
                VALUES (new_dep_name)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE d_name = new_dep_name;

            SELECT d_id INTO dept_id FROM department WHERE d_name = new_dep_name;

            INSERT INTO Student_Department  (s_id, d_id)
                VALUES (student_id, dept_id);

            ...

            SET index = index + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Is there any way, to optimize multiple inserts in stored procedure?

Comment: How do you want to optimize it? is it too slow, or something else?

Comment: how you obtain the student_id?  .. you use another select  ?

Comment: You are doing an unnecessary IODKU for existing departments each time through this loop.